# How to easily check if undefined in javascript object?

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have a javascript object "myobject" that just contains an empty object "{}".

I ideally in my code I want to do the following:

```
if (theobject[keyvar][subkeyvar]) {
  // do something
}
```

The issue now is that because keyvar and subkeyvar do not actually exist within the object, it fails and comains that the properties are undefined. What is the simplest/least lines of code/best way to be able to do have it just "know it is undefined" and continue to execute the //do something or not without crashing?

I dont want to get too carried away with checking like:

```
if( keyvar in theobject ) {
   if(subkeyvar in theobject) {
        if.....
   }
}
```

Comment: If they both can possibly be undefined, you have to test one, then the other.

Comment: but note that those tests don't just check for undefined but also for 0, null, NaN, false and "".

Comment: `if(theobject[keyvar] && theobject[keyvar][subkeyvar])`?

Comment: If you're checking for existence, use `in`. If you're checking for a value, use `===`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (typeof theobject[keyvar] !== "undefined" && typeof theobject[keyvar][subkeyvar] !== "undefined") {
  // keyvar and subkeyvar defined

}
```

first we check if keyvar typeof is undefined and then if subkeyvar is undefined and if they are both defined `typeof theobject[keyvar] !== "undefined" && typeof theobject[keyvar][subkeyvar] !== "undefined"` is true.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If they both can possibly be undefined, you have to test one, then the other.

```
if (theobject[keyvar] && theobject[keyvar][subkeyvar]) {
```

This will of course fail on a key containing `0` or `""` (or several other falsey but not undefined values) so you may want to use `typeof` on the second test.

Answer (score 0):

```
theObject.hasOwnProperty(keyvar) && theObject.hasOwnProperty[keyvar].hasOwnProperty(subkeyvar)
```

Comment: What if the property is defined in the prototype chain?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
if (theobject[keyvar] && theobject[keyvar][subkeyvar]) {

    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (theobject[keyvar] !== undefined && theobject[keyvar][subkeyvar] !== undefined) {
    // do something
}
```

Since the `&&` operator is used, the `if` will not check the second value if the first value is falsey, so you will never get the 'properties are undefined` error